# jersey 1.17 how to get reponse body when status returned in 401

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-client, http-status-code-401

I have a question on how to fetch response body in Jersey client when server returns some sample text with status code `401`. Sample service is setup as follows:

```
@GET
@Path("test401withcontent")
public Response get401TestWithContent()
{
    return Response.status(401).entity("return some text").build();     
}
```

On the client side (using Jersey 1.17) `ClientResponse.getEntity` prints `null`.
Noticed that `content-length` of headers has the right number (16 in this case.)

Is there a different way to get response when return code is `401`?

Comment: What frameworks is the server using?  Most such as Spring Web MVC do not return a response body on a 401 as it is implied by status code.

Comment: can you add the headers from the response to the question?

Comment: The service that is designed should handle all REST requests and all responses. I setup a glassfish, jersey rest endpoint to serve 401 with some response. Interestingly POSTMAN get requst shows the return code (401) and response body whatever sample text sent by the sever.

Comment: The following headers are returned: \"Date\":[\"Tue, 22 Nov 2016 21:37:52 GMT\"],
  \"Content-Length\":[\"18\"],
  \"Content-Type\":[\"text/html\"],
  \"X-Powered-By\":[\"Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  Java/Oracle Corporation/1.7)\"],
  \"Server\":[\"GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0\"]}",

Comment: thats weird. There's nothing in jersey client source code to stop reading a body (unless the status code is 204) and I've got lots of contrary examples that work fine within applications I've written.  Can you add your client code to the question, there's not really enough info to work on

Answer (score 0):

Have deployed you method to my test web site and used below client got currect response.

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
         //System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");


          Response response = client.target(
          "http://jerseyexample-ravikant.rhcloud.com/rest/jws/test401withcontent").
         request().get(); System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
```